# Beautify search result in search engine

Tags: layout, seo, search-engine

Suppose I search *Twitter* in Google.

Unlike ordinary website, google will present Twiiter with an additional table,
which  provides links like *Sign Up for Twitter*, *Twitter (@twitter) on Twitter*.

[image: Example]

I am wondering:

1. How to do this?
2. what is this called(beautify the search result),Is this called *SEO*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called [Sitelinks](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=47334)

Answer (score 0):

Dear there is nothing to do for you to get such type of search result.
Google webmaster tools offer you this feature called as "sitelinks" it automatically generate this type search result when ever user type your domian name as keyword in search box.

Even more you have choice to set what URL should appear in SIX PACK result, And you will get it in Google webmaster tool section.